# Read files in subfolders

Tags: vbscript, text-files, subdirectory

I'm trying to make a script that we can output a specific string ino a files from a list of files in different subfolders.

My script works but onl for one directory. I need some help to make it works with subfolders

```
Const ForReading = 1
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = objFSO.GetFolder("D:\vbs\logs\") ' here i have loads of subfolders with *.txt 
Set outfile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("D:\vbs\ok\test.txt") ' my output file

for each file in folder.Files
    Set testfile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(file.path, ForReading)

    Do While Not testfile.AtEndOfStream

        If instr (testfile.readline, "central") then ' i output every lines where there is the word "central" 
            outfile.writeline testfile.readline
        End If

        if instr (testfile.readline, "version") then  ' i use this to parse my output file to get a indication between every files read

            num = testfile.readline
            mag = Split(num)
        elseif testfile.AtEndOfStream = true then
            outfile.writeline "Shop " & mag(4)
        end if
    Loop
    testfile.close
next
outfile.close
```

Comment: There tools for this task - e.g. findstr or grep. Use them or state why not.

Comment: I really want to use VBS cause i have spend much time to come there. Now if only i can use it in subfolders i would be proud of me ( i am  beginner )

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9454363/603855 for a step by step introduction to work with files in recursive traversal; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16895790/603855 for an idea to get a list of all files in a folder tree that then can be processed sequentially.

Answer (score 2):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14965606/1630171) to a similar question for a folder recursion example.

One remark about your existing code, though: each call of the `ReadLine` method reads the next line from the file, so something like this:

```
If instr (testfile.readline, "central") then
  outfile.writeline testfile.readline
End If
```

will **not** output the line containing the word "central" (as your comments say), but the line **after** that line.

If you want to output the line containing the word you're checking for, you have to store the read line in a variable and continue with that variable:

```
line = testfile.ReadLine
If InStr(line, "central") Then
  outfile.WriteLine line
End If
```

Comment: @ekkehard.horner Thanks for fixing the typo. I think I should go to bed now ... ;-\

Answer (score 0):

I would encapsulate your entire `For...Each` block into a new subroutine and then add a new `For...Each` block to capture all `subFolders` in the parent folder. I added that functionality to your script, see below.

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const Start_Folder = "D:\vbs\logs\" ' here i have loads of subfolders with *.txt 

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set outfile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("D:\vbs\ok\test.txt") ' my output file


'Call the Search subroutine to start the recursive search.
Search objFSO.GetFolder(Start_Folder)

'Close the outfile after all folders have been searched
outfile.Close

Sub Search(sDir)

    for each file in sDir.Files
        Set testfile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(file.path, ForReading)

        Do While Not testfile.AtEndOfStream

            If instr (testfile.readline, "central") then ' i output every lines where there is the word "central" 
                outfile.writeline testfile.readline
            End If

            if instr (testfile.readline, "version") then  ' i use this to parse my output file to get a indication between every files read

                num = testfile.readline
                mag = Split(num)
            elseif testfile.AtEndOfStream = true then
                outfile.writeline "Shop " & mag(4)
            end if
        Loop
        testfile.close
    next

    'Find EACH SUBFOLDER.
    For Each subFolder In sDir.SubFolders

        'Call the Search subroutine to start the recursive search on EACH SUBFOLDER.
        Search objFSO.GetFolder(subFolder.Path)
    Next

End Sub
```